# P(R) represents a pattern drawn by Julia in R rows. The following pattern represents P(5)

Tags: mysql

I recently started learning  mysql and got stuck in this question:

P(R) represents a pattern drawn by Julia in R rows. The following pattern represents P(5):
Write a query to print the pattern P(20).

[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrDGn.png)

I have written the answer like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
BEGIN
DECLARE CH VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE CT INT DEFAULT 20;
SET CH = ' *';
WHILE CT>0 DO
    SELECT REPEAT(CH,CT);
    SET CT=CT-1;
    END WHILE
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Somehow it's not working..what's missing?

Comment: what mean "Somehow it's not working." ... you have error?   . wrong result?  ..

Comment: it says this: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE CH VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE CT INT DEFAULT 20;
SET CH = ' *';
WHILE CT>0 DO' at line 2

Answer (score 3):

```
set @number = 0;
select repeat('* ', @number := @number + 1) from information_schema.tables limit 20;
```

This worked for me!

Comment: why does this work when selecting from information_schema.tables but not just as a select statement?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors in your code. Try this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `DoPattern`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE DoPattern()
BEGIN
    DECLARE CT INT(10) DEFAULT 20;
    DECLARE CH VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT " *";
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `pattern` (`rowno` INT(2) UNSIGNED, `pattern_string` VARCHAR(50)) ENGINE=MEMORY;

    WHILE CT > 0 DO
        INSERT INTO `pattern` (`rowno`,`pattern_string`) VALUES (CT,REPEAT(CH,CT));
        SET CT = CT - 1;
    END WHILE;

    SELECT `pattern_string` FROM `pattern` ORDER BY `rowno` DESC;
    DROP TABLE `pattern`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL DoPattern();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @i INT = 20
WHILE (@i > 0) 
BEGIN
   PRINT REPLICATE('* ', @i) 
   SET @i = @i - 1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
set @i = 21;
select repeat('* ', @i := @i-1) from information_schema.tables;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with recursive num(n) as
(
select 40
    union all
    select n - 2
    from num 
    where n - 2 >= 2
)
select lpad('', num.n, '* ')
from num;
```

#The question is to create a pattern for P(20), it has total of 40 characters(including spaces). So I've created num table with 40 numbers. Then using lpad function (basically left pads the entered string(' ') upto certain length (num.n) with another string('* ').
That's the answer

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short solution using loops and "REPLICATE" function in MS SQL:

```
     DECLARE @R INT = 20;
     WHILE @R > 0
     BEGIN
        DECLARE @C AS VARCHAR(max)
        SET @C = (SELECT REPLICATE('*\n', @R))
        PRINT replace(@C,'\n',char(10))
        SET @R = @R- 1;
     END
```

Here is the long solution using loops and without "REPLICATE" function:

```
    DECLARE @r INT = 20
    DECLARE @i INT = 0
    DECLARE @F varchar(max) = ''
    WHILE @i < @r
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @j INT = 0
        DECLARE @o varchar(max) = ''
        WHILE @j < @r - @i
        BEGIN
            SET @o = @o + '* '
            SET @j += 1
        END

        SET @i += 1
        SET @F = @F + @o + CHAR(10)
    END
    PRINT @F
```

***Note***: If you do not see the ******* printed in a triangle pattern, then it has to do with what you specify in "**char(?)**"

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1
WHILE (@i < 21) 
BEGIN
   PRINT REPLICATE('* ', @i) 
   SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT REPEAT('* ', @NUMBER := @NUMBER - 1) FROM information_schema.tables, (SELECT @NUMBER:=21) t LIMIT 20;

Comment: format your code and provide an explanation please.